# Using regex lookahead, egrep

Tags: regex, grep, regex-lookarounds

If your file contains

```
apples are good
apple cider is also good
```

Why would `egrep '(?=apples)app' file` fail to pick up any lines?

Using egrep 2.5.1 on MAC

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Extended regular expression doesn't have positive look-ahead feature.
See [the regex flavor comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)

Comment: On mac OS, you can get GNU grep (which has PCRE support) through [homebrew-dupes](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes)

Comment: The link above no longer seems to have a "regex flavor comparison".  It is basically now just a site hawking the "Regex Buddy" program for $39.95.  I think something like the flavor comparison is available here:  http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/regexp.html but it's astonishingly difficult to find information on this.

Comment: You can do this on Linux using the '-P' flag: **-P, --perl-regexp: Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression.  This is  highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.** What's unusual is that the BSD version (Mac, Darwin, vis-a-vis year 2010) references '-P' tangentially at the bottom of the documentation but does not define it as a usable flag. Mac users can download a newer version of [Grep at the Gnu site](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/). It's surprising that even OS X 10.9 is bundled with an old version with many bugs.

Comment: The grep on macOS is not an older GNU grep; it's just not GNU at all. So it doesn't have GNU extensions.