# A number not containing the digit 5

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to use negative look-ahead as per [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17328119/2725810) to match numbers not containing the digit 5:

```
echo "aaa 123467890 3456 bbb" | egrep '[(?!5)[:digit:]]+'
```

The color output shows that the second number is matched. How do I fix this?

Is there a way with `egrep` to exclude `5` from the class `[:digit:]`? (I performed a number of searches, but could not find anything to this end)

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `[012346789]+`?

Comment: Look around doesn't work within a character class. Use `[0-46-9]+`

Comment: @lolbas This is just an example to learn a more general approach, which would work with a larger class (e.g. matching a pattern involving a lower-case letter which is not `m`).

Comment: You don't need look-ahead for this.  Just add anchors to the expression or  `-w`, e.g.: `grep -wE '[0-46-9]+'`

Comment: maybe you are looking for `\b(?:(?!5)\d)+\b`

Comment: Wonder if egrep [would even support lookarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10645676/5527985). However you can use eg [`grep -oP '\b[^\D5]+\b'`](https://regex101.com/r/4Ie736/2) or for you [other concern something like this](https://regex101.com/r/4Ie736/1/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with your regex:

1. `egrep` (as in POSIX extended regular expressions) does not support look-ahead or look-behind at all.
2. Even if it did, `[(?!5)[:digit:]]` is a single character class equivalent to `[[:digit:]()!?]`. `(` doesn't have any special meaning in a character class.

Unfortunately `egrep` doesn't support negated named character classes either (as in `[[:^digit:]]`).

That leaves you only two options:

- Manually compute the set difference and list it explicitly:

  ```
  egrep '[0-46-9]+'
  ```
- Switch to PCRE and use a Perl-style regex, either

  ```
  grep -P '[^\D5]+'
  ```

  (the trick that uses double negation and set union to compute a set difference: we match any character that is not a non-digit or `5`) or

  ```
  grep -P '(?:(?!5)\d)+'
  ```

  (look-ahead version, fixed).